# Azure Functions System.Net.Primitives: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'host')

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

When I send an HTTP request to the function, It shows this error on console output, and returns HTTP 500 status code without hitting the the break point of function's first line.

> Executed 'Validate' (Failed, Id=548b4612-42f8-4e49-886a-da6888045c32,
> Duration=343ms) System.Net.Primitives: Value cannot be null.
> (Parameter 'host') An unhandled host error has occurred.
> System.Net.Primitives: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'host').

[image]

Function

```
[FunctionName("Validate")]
public async Task Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] string req,
[SignalR(HubName = "PubSub")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessageQueue)
{
    ...
}
```

---

host.json

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
  "applicationInsights": {
    "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
    "samplingSettings": {
      "isEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

---

.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>ZulaMobile.Lobby.StoreValidation</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.30" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="3.1.21" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\zulamobile-azure-lobby-common\zulamobile-azure-lobby-common.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Functions\CafeBazaar\" />
    <Folder Include="Huawei\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Could you post your dependencies from the csproj?

Comment: @misha130 I added the whole .csproj.

Comment: This only happens locally, right?

Comment: Yes, I didn't try it on Azure yet.

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT Hi Ajay, It was a DI problem as far as I remember. So it resolved. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same issue but it worked fine at my end.
Followed by this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-csharp) & demo [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/main/samples/QuickStartServerless/csharp) project ,

- Created a Signal IR in Azure portal .

Open the download folder from my VS Code-

And added the following packages into my local here is my `.csproj` file

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="content\index.html">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And make sure that you have added your connection string in your `local settings.json`   which have to copy from portal from `Azure signalIR > Keys>Connection string.`

[image]

[image]

Here are some screenshot for reference output:
[image]

[image]

**Note: If still facing the same issue you can try to Un install the [`Azure function V3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v3,windows,csharp,portal,bash,keda#v2) and install it again .**

For more information please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243467/azure-function-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source) .